# Python keras TypeError: Invalid shape () for image data

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

I am trying to plot misclassified images but I am facing an error saying: `TypeError: Invalid shape () for image data`

My validation is defined as follow:

```
validation = data.flow_from_directory(data_dir,
                                      class_mode = "categorical",
                                      target_size = (X, Y),
                                      color_mode="rgb",
                                      batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                                      shuffle = False,
                                      subset='validation',
                                      seed = 42)
```

and my function to plot misclassified images is defined as follow:

```
predictions = model.predict(validation)     # Vector of probabilities
pred_labels = np.argmax(predictions, axis = 1) # We take the highest probability

test_labels_vector = np.argmax(validation.classes)
def classification_evaluation(classification, predicted_labels, test_labels, test_images):
    if classification== "correct":
        indices_list = np.where(predicted_labels == validation.classes)[0]
    else:
        indices_list = np.where(predicted_labels!= validation.classes)[0]
    test_images_filtered= [validation.classes[i] for i in indices_list]
    images_labels_original= [validation.classes[i] for i in indices_list]
    images_labels_predicted= [pred_labels[i] for i in indices_list]
    print(f"{len(test_images_filtered)} images were classified {classification.upper()} out of a total of {len(test_images)} in the Test dataset")

    unique, counts = np.unique(images_labels_original, return_counts=True)
    for i in range(0,len(unique)):
        print(f"for category {unique[i]} the number of {classification.upper()} classified images were: {counts[i]}")
        
    # Plot some of the misclassified images
    print("\n\n")
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(5,2)
    fig.suptitle(f"Sample of {classification.upper()} Classified Images", fontsize=20)
    fig.set_size_inches(15,15)
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range (2):
            l=random.randint(0,len(test_images_filtered))
            ax[i,j].imshow(test_images_filtered[l])
            ax[i,j].set_title("Predicted: "+str(images_labels_predicted[l])+"\n"+"Actual: "+str(images_labels_original[l]))
    plt.tight_layout()

classification_evaluation("incorrect", pred_labels, test_labels_vector, validation.classes)
```

The track of the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/2783498455.py in <module>
----> 1 classification_evaluation("incorrect", pred_labels, test_labels_vector, validation.classes)

/tmp/ipykernel_17/3357022360.py in classification_evaluation(classification, predicted_labels, test_labels, test_images)
     21         for j in range (2):
     22             l=random.randint(0,len(test_images_filtered))
---> 23             ax[i,j].imshow(test_images_filtered[l])
     24             print(ax[i,j].imshow(test_images_filtered[l]))
     25             ax[i,j].set_title("Predicted: "+str(images_labels_predicted[l])+"\n"+"Actual: "+str(images_labels_original[l]))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    457                 "parameter will become keyword-only %(removal)s.",
    458                 name=name, obj_type=f"parameter of {func.__name__}()")
--> 459         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    460 
    461     # Don't modify *func*'s signature, as boilerplate.py needs it.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1412     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1413         if data is None:
-> 1414             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1415 
   1416         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, interpolation_stage, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5485                               **kwargs)
   5486 
-> 5487         im.set_data(X)
   5488         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5489         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
    714                 or self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):
    715             raise TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data"
--> 716                             .format(self._A.shape))
    717 
    718         if self._A.ndim == 3:

TypeError: Invalid shape () for image data
```

After changing, `test_images_filtered= [validation.classes[i] for i in indices_list]` to `test_images_filtered= [validation.filepaths[i] for i in indices_list]`

and:

```
ax[i,j].imshow(test_images_filtered[l])
```

to

```
ax[i,j].imshow(plt.imread(test_images_filtered[l]))
```

I have one image plotted but with an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/2783498455.py in <module>
----> 1 classification_evaluation("incorrect", pred_labels, test_labels_vector, validation.classes)

/tmp/ipykernel_17/2305134943.py in classification_evaluation(classification, predicted_labels, test_labels, test_images)
     23             l=random.randint(0,len(test_images_filtered))
     24             #ax[i,j].imshow(test_images_filtered[l])
---> 25             ax[i,j].imshow(plt.imread(test_images_filtered[l]))
     26             ax[i,j].set_title("Predicted: "+str(images_labels_predicted[l])+"\n"+"Actual: "+str(images_labels_original[l]))
     27     plt.tight_layout()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It is likely that you have invalid image files in your directory. You may verify them by some codes like this one: https://gist.github.com/Kaveh8/9a8e1097b76c8ee92a4644f4413fa57f#file-chech_invalid_images-py

Comment: @Kaveh, thanks for your answer. I checked by applying the example code that you gave me, but it didn't find any invalid image files in my directory.

Comment: You are trying to plot data in `test_images_filtered` tensor, which is defined like `test_images_filtered= [validation.classes[i] for i in indices_list]`. It seems that this array contains labels instead of image data.

Comment: There is a way to modify it?

Comment: An example: change above line to `test_images_filtered= [validation.filepaths[i] for i in indices_list]` to store path of images into a vector instead of their labels. Then change  the line `ax[i,j].imshow(test_images_filtered[l])` to `ax[i,j].imshow(plt.imread(test_images_filtered[l]))`

Comment: Thanks @Kaveh for your help. I did the modification. One image is plotted now but I have one error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. I updated the post